# Gradle project sync failed right after creating

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

My error:

[image]

I've just created a new project (Empty Activity, API 19) in Android Studio and got this error. I haven't written a single letter. I tried deleting .gradle  folder and 'redownloading' the gradle but it didn't work. Older projects, that I created and worked on, load and run without any issues. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been using Android Studio 4.2, this seems to be a known issue that a lot of people are facing.

To fix this, you need to make the following change, in the **"build.gradle"** file which you can find in your project's root folder.

***Change this line***

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0-release-764"
```

***To***

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
```

Comment: The Kotlin Gradle plugin is defined in the root build.gradle file: `classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")`